# Why does the client stop seeing the movement of other players in an online game after switching the scene in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

If you do not try to move to another location, the player sees the other player and his movement, otherwise the player sees only the player, but not his movement. I tried to clear the groups, but it didn't help. I want you to see the movement of the other player when you switch the scene, if there is one there. I use phaser 3, mysql2.

Client code

```js
const socket = io();

class BaseScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(key) {
        super({ key });
        this.spawned = false;
        this.otherPlayers = {};
        this.nicknames = {};
    }

    create() {
        const self = this;
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        this.otherPlayers = this.physics.add.group();

    }

    update() {
        if (this.player && this.player.body) {
            let moved = false;

            if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityX(-160);
                moved = true;
            } else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityX(160);
                moved = true;
            } else {
                this.player.setVelocityX(0);
            }

            if (this.cursors.up.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityY(-160);
                moved = true;
            } else if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityY(160);
                moved = true;
            } else {
                this.player.setVelocityY(0);
            }

            if (moved) {
                socket.emit('playerMovement', { x: this.player.x, y: this.player.y });
            }
        }
    }
}
class FirstScene extends BaseScene {
    constructor() {
        super('first');
    }

    create() {
        super.create();
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'LOCATION 1');

        socket.emit('createPlayer');

        socket.on('playerCreated', (playerData) => {
            addPlayer(this, playerData);
            this.trigger = this.add.rectangle(400, -12, 100, 100, 0xffffff).setDisplaySize(50, 50);

            this.physics.add.existing(this.trigger, true);
            this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.trigger, (player, trigger) => {
                socket.emit('TriggerFirstScene', player);
            }); 
            });

        socket.on('playerMoved', (playerData) => {
            playerMoved(this, playerData);
        });

        socket.on('newPlayer', (players) => {
            addOtherPlayer(this, players);
        });


        socket.on('TriggerFirstScene', (playerData) => {
            this.scene.switch('second');
        }); 

    }

    update() {
        super.update();
     }
}
class SecondScene extends BaseScene {
    constructor() {
        super('second');
    }

    create() {
        super.create();
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'LOCATION 2');

        socket.emit('createPlayer2');

        socket.on('playerCreated2', playerData => {
            addPlayer(this, playerData);
            this.trigger = this.add.rectangle(400, -12, 100, 100, 0xffffff).setDisplaySize(50, 50);

            this.physics.add.existing(this.trigger, true);
            this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.trigger, (player, trigger) => {
                socket.emit('TriggerSecondScene', this.player);
            });

            socket.on('TriggerSecondScene', (playerData) => {
                this.scene.switch('first');
            });
        });

        socket.on('playerMoved2', (playerData) => {
            playerMoved(this, playerData);
        });

        socket.on('newPlayer2', (players) => {
            addOtherPlayer(this, players);
        });

    }

    update() {
        super.update();
        // other none duplicate code
        // ...
    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 700,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 0 }
        }
    },
    scene: [FirstScene, SecondScene]
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function addPlayer(self, playerData) {
    self.player = self.physics.add.image(playerData.x, playerData.y, 'player').setDisplaySize(100, 100);
    self.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    self.player.playerId = playerData.playerId;
}

function addOtherPlayer(self, players) {
    players.forEach((playerData) => {
        const existingPlayer = self.otherPlayers.getChildren().find((otherPlayer) => otherPlayer.playerId === playerData.id);

        if (!existingPlayer) {
            this.otherPlayer = self.physics.add.sprite(playerData.x_position, playerData.y_position, 'player').setDisplaySize(100, 100);
            this.otherPlayer.playerId = playerData.id;
            self.otherPlayers.add(otherPlayer);
        }
    });
}

function playerMoved(self, playerData) {
    self.otherPlayers.getChildren().forEach((otherPlayer) => {
        if (playerData.playerId === otherPlayer.playerId) {
            otherPlayer.setPosition(playerData.x, playerData.y);
        }
    });
}
```

Server code

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user connected');

    if (socket.handshake.session && socket.handshake.session.user) {
        socket.on('createPlayer', async () => {
            try {
                const userId = socket.handshake.session.user.id;
                socket.emit('currentUserId', userId);

                const [rows] = await pool.query('SELECT  `id`, `nickname`, `login`, `password`, `age`, `x_position`, `y_position`, `clan`, `post`, `location`, `created_at` FROM `users` WHER WHERE id = ?', [userId]);

                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    let playerData = {
                        playerId: userId,
                        x: rows[0].x_position,
                        y: rows[0].y_position,
                        nickname: rows[0].nickname,
                    };

                    socket.emit('playerCreated', playerData);

                    const [rows2] = await pool.query('SELECT  `id`, `nickname`, `age`, `x_position`, `y_position`, `location`, `created_at` FROM users WHERE id != ? AND location = ?', [userId, 1]);

                    socket.emit('newPlayer', rows2)
                } else {
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                
            }
        });

        socket.on('createPlayer2', async () => {
            try {
                const userId = socket.handshake.session.user.id;
                socket.emit('currentUserId', userId);

                const [rows] = await pool.query('SELECT  `id`, `nickname`, `age`, `x_position`, `y_position`, `location`, `created_at` FROM `users` WHERE id = ? AND location = ?', [userId, 2]);

                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    let playerData = {
                        playerId: userId,
                        x: rows[0].x_position,
                        y: rows[0].y_position,
                        nickname: rows[0].nickname,
                    };

                    socket.emit('playerCreated2', playerData);

                    const [rows2] = await pool.query('SELECT  `id`, `nickname`, `age`, `x_position`, `y_position`, `location`, `created_at` FROM users WHERE id != ? AND location = ? ', [userId, 2]);
                    socket.emit('newPlayer2', rows2)
                } else {
                   
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });

        socket.on('playerMovement', async (data) => {
            try {
                const userId = socket.handshake.session.user.id;
                const { x, y } = data;

                await pool.query('UPDATE users SET x_position = ?, y_position = ? WHERE id = ?', [x, y, userId]);

                socket.broadcast.emit('playerMoved', { playerId: userId, x, y });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });

app.get('/game.html', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('game', { user: req.session.user });
});

server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error starting the server:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Server is running on http://localhost:3000');
    }
});
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean. Can you explain your problem in more detail? Which player should or should not be seen?

Comment: when switching the scene, the client stops seeing the movement of other players. if you do not switch, everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a MySQL problem? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well honestly I don't really understand, what you want to achieve with your code, it is far to complicated.

**THAT** said there are some issue here:

1. If you switch from `FirstScene` to `SecondScene`, the socket events `playerMoved` might trigger *(I'm not 100% sure if phaser will not put them to sleep or not)*, BUT they are triggering on the `FirstScene`, since `playerMoved(this, playerData);` is scoped in the `FirstScene`.
2. In the `SecondScene` you are only quering the players in the location 2, and I can't see any code "moving" the player to that new location.

**A Code structure that would be more readable / structured / easy to debug:**
*(Simply have one Scene, that manages the other scenes)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';
console.clear();

class FirstScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super('FirstScene');
    }
    
    create(){
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'In FirstScene, Click to change').setOrigin(0);
        this.message = this.add.text(10, 30, 'Wating for data...').setOrigin(0);
        this.events.on('mgr-update', data => this.message.setText(`Data: ${data}`));
        this.input.on('pointerdown', () => this.events.emit('change-scene'));
    }
}

class SecondScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super('SecondScene');
    }
    
    create(){
        this.add.text(10, 10, 'In SecondScene, Click to change').setOrigin(0);
        this.message = this.add.text(10, 30, 'Wating for data...').setOrigin(0);
        this.events.on('mgr-update', data => this.message.setText(`Data: ${data}`));
        this.input.on('pointerdown', () => this.events.emit('change-scene'));
    }
}

class ManagerScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super('ManagerScene');
    }
    
    create(){
        let counter = 0;
        this.currentScene = 'FirstScene';
        this.scene.launch(this.currentScene);

        this.scene.get('FirstScene').events.on('change-scene', () => {
            this.currentScene = 'SecondScene';
            this.scene.launch('SecondScene');
            this.scene.sleep('FirstScene');
        });
        
        this.scene.get('SecondScene').events.on('change-scene', () => {
            this.currentScene = 'FirstScene';
            this.scene.launch('FirstScene');
            this.scene.sleep('SecondScene');
        });
        
        // for-the-demo sends every second the counter-value
        setInterval( () =>  this.scene.get(this.currentScene).events.emit('mgr-update', counter++), 500);
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: [ManagerScene, SecondScene, FirstScene, ],
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> **Basically:** In the manager Scene you would put the whole `socket` logic, and it would pass the data to the corresponding Scenes. This would keep the complexity and the count of eventlistener low.